# Sentence that I find odd

Tags: translation, tense

So the title of a video I've watched for immersion (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmd_p5qnzCM) is the following :
天の川がアンドロメダと衝突したとき何が起こるか

I would translate it to something like "When the milky way collided with Andromeda, what happens" and that makes no sense to me. The problem is, it has not yet happened ( I'm talking about the andromeda and milky way collision), so I thought it shouldn't be present?

Can you explain this to me?

Comment: So if I actually understand what you sent me (I didn't know this, thanks!), a more suitable translation would be "When the Milky Way collides with Andromeda, what happens?" right?

Comment: Yes. Or more unambiguously, "Immediately after the Milky Way collides with Andromeda, what happens".

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer!